# Nesting callbacks for more than two tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

It is possible to determine the order of **TWO tasks** using callbacks, as shown below.

```
a(b);

function a(callback) {
   // do something
   callback();
}

function b() {
   // do next
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gulli/11ugxrse/)

First do `a()`, then do `b()`.

I would like to concatenate **more than two tasks**.
As I´m dealing with quite big functions, I´m looking for something like that:

```
a(b(c));
```

First do `a()`, then do `b()`, then do `c()`.
However I'm not successful with this. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gulli/gwm5ukco/)

Is there an easy way to do so, maybe without needing Promises?

Comment: ?? Just make `b()` look like `a()` so that it calls its callback. It's not really clear what you're talking about.

Comment: If you really just want to call three synchronous functions in a row, then why not just `a(); b(); c();`.  Why deal with callbacks at all if you aren't passing state to them and there are no async operations involved?

Comment: Exactly this is the problem. The three functions must have a clear execution order, because `c` waits for a value from `b` and `b` for a value from `a`. If `c` is called before `b`, `c` returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `b` immediately, not passing a callback to `a`. You'll need to use a function expression:

```
a(function(aResult) {
    b(c);
});
```

Of course, you can avoid these by returning closures from all your functions:

```
function a(callback) {
    return function(args) {
        // do something
        if (callback) callback(res);
    };
}
function b(callback) {
    return function(aResult) {
        // do next
        if (callback) callback(res);
    };
}
function c(callback) {
    return function(bResult) {
        // do next
        if (callback) callback(res);
    };
}
```

which you would call like this:

```
a(b(c())();
```

(this is known as pure [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style))

Comment: I tried your example, but I only get the result of `a()`. See http://jsfiddle.net/gulli/zkx2crw8/

Comment: @wurstbrotrest: Because you're not doing anything in the functions and not producing results - you can see a `ReferenceError` in the console. See [this updated example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkx2crw8/1/)

Comment: Just a word of caution: No one uses this in the wild, it's rather uncommon. It might be elegant, but it's rather complicated, so better comment heavily.